# Validating the exception in Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit

Can anyone help me in implementing the expected Exception in Nunit?. 
in my Nunit test method it will make a method call which will throw Exception, I need to validate the exception in Nunit using Expected Exception

Thanks in Advance

Comment: NUnit has extensive documentation - what exact problem are you having? http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks. Used the following code to solve the issue
[ExpectedException(typeof(ErrorCodeException))]